# Can foreign keys act as a primary key?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

If a table has a composite primary key made of attribute A, B and this composite primary key is referenced in another table, can that other table have attribute A as a primary key and NOT attribute b? And maybe, Attribute A with some other attribute in the same table as another composite primary key?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [relationship attributes in ER diagrams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700196/relationship-attributes-in-er-diagrams)

Answer (score 1):

If the second table has both attributes A and B, then an FK constraint can reference those same attributes in the first table (since they're uniquely constrained as the PK), regardless of whether A and/or B are part of the PK of the second table or not.

Comment: Does that mean yes? Sorry I don't quite understand. I don't know what FK constraint is. Too advanced.

I want to use part of a composite foreign key as part of a composite primary key, and reference this composite primary key (composed of composite foreign keys) in another table.

Comment: FK constraint means foreign key constraint. It's what you declare in your schema to enforce the validity of foreign keys. As long as you reference the whole PK of your first table, some or all of those attributes in your second table can be part of the primary key or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  One fairly common example is a general ledger.  The Item table has a composite key, consisting of Transaction Number and Item Number (within transaction). The Transaction table has a key of Transaction Number, referenced by one of the key fields in Item.
General ledger systems aren't always designed this way, but they often are.